# How to update only "hour" part in a datetime field in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

Is there a way to update only Hour part in a DateTime field?? If not, how do I update the time part in Oracle? I tried this->

```
update tab_name 
set C_Name=to_date('04/03/2012 00:31:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') 
where C_Name1=10484;
```

didn't work as I'm updating '00' in Hour part.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've taken the liberty of formatting your question for you. In the future, please format your questions before posting them.

Comment: Is `C_NAME` a DATE?  How would this only update the time?  Do you want the day portion of the string to be ignored (i.e. update `C_NAME` to be whatever day `C_NAME` is currently at 12:31:00 AM?)

Comment: yeah Justin,C_Name is a DateTime field.No,I dont want anything to be ignored here,as yu said 12:31:00 AM here only "12" has to be replaced with "00",it should be 00:31:00 AM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I knew I wanted to update just one part of the time I'd probably convert to a string with the value I want in the appropriate place, then convert back to a date. Say I wanted the minutes to be "31":

```
update tab_name 
set C_Name=
  to_date( 
    to_char(C_Name, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:"31":SS'),
    'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
  ) 
where C_Name1=10484;
```

If you want to modify the time portion relative to its current value (to add 2 hours or subtract 3 seconds, for example) then there are some choices for date arithemtic. The Oracle documentation is very good for these things.

Comment: Adam,thanks for the reply,but this didn`t work for me when I did like this--->update tab_name 
 set C_Name=to_date(to_char(C_Name, 'MM/DD/YYYY "00":HH:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') where C_Name1=10484;...Hour I made it "00",it still saving it as "12"...Any solution for this???

Comment: @palak - Are you sure you're just not displaying it in 12-hour time format rather than 24-hour time format?  If you display the time using the `HH24` format mask, it will be displayed in the 24-hour time format so between midnight and 1 AM, the hour will be "00".  If you display the time using the `HH` format mask, it will be displayed in the 12-hour time format so the hour will always be between 1 and 12. In the database, dates are not stored with a format, they're always stored in the same non-human readable packed binary format. A date must be converted to a string to become human readable

Comment: Justin,In UI I`m displaying LocalTime,but in database i`m saving it in 12 hour format,now the main problem is->When datetime is saved between 6 and 6:30 AM,in UI it`s displaying it as PM.I think in Database I`ll have to make it as HH24 as yu said..